# Pandas sort_value() issue. Wrong sorting integer when applied key parameter

Tags: python, pandas

Hi everyone I have tried to look everywhere for this issue but I cannot figure a solution out. I'd be glad if you'd help me.

So, basically I have this dataset:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'kkk', 'www', 'www'],
                 "col2": [ 2020, 1994, 2013, 1000, 1996, 2021]})

df.dtypes
col1    object
col2     int64
dtype: object
```

and I want to order the first column with a costum order and the second column with ascending order. The final result should be the following:

```py
    col1    col2
4    www    1996
5    www    2021
3    kkk    1000
0    xxx    1994
1    xxx    2013
2    xxx    2020
```

So, in order to accomplish that I do this:

```py
d = {'xxx': 4, 'zzz':1, 'yyy':5, 'kkk':2, 'jjj':3, 'www':0} # to customize order 

df.sort_values(by = ['col1' , 'col2'], key = lambda x: x.map(d))
```

but I end up with this:

```py
    col1    col2
4    www    1996
5    www    2021
3    kkk    1000
0    xxx    2020
1    xxx    1994
2    xxx    2013
```

If I only do:

```py
df.sort_values(by = ['col1' , 'col2'])

    col1    col2
3    kkk    1000
4    www    1996
5    www    2021
1    xxx    1994
2    xxx    2013
0    xxx    2020
```

The col2 is ordered fine. I really don't know why I am having this issue. Has anyone experienced something similar? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible trick is expand dictionary by values from `col2`:

```
d = {'xxx': 4, 'zzz':1, 'yyy':5, 'kkk':2, 'jjj':3, 'www':0} # to customize order 
d = {**d, **dict(zip(df.col2, df.col2))}

df = df.sort_values(by = ['col1' , 'col2'], key = lambda x: x.map(d))
print (df)
  col1  col2
4  www  1996
5  www  2021
3  kkk  1000
1  xxx  1994
2  xxx  2013
0  xxx  2020
```

Or solution with `get` - if no match is returned same value instead `NaN`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = ['col1' , 'col2'], key = lambda x: x.map(lambda y: d.get(y, y)))
print (df)
  col1  col2
4  www  1996
5  www  2021
3  kkk  1000
1  xxx  1994
2  xxx  2013
0  xxx  2020
```

Solution with helper column:

```
d = {'xxx': 4, 'zzz':1, 'yyy':5, 'kkk':2, 'jjj':3, 'www':0} 

df = df.assign(new=df['col1'].map(d)).sort_values(by=['new','col2']).drop('new', axis=1)
print (df)
  col1  col2
4  www  1996
5  www  2021
3  kkk  1000
1  xxx  1994
2  xxx  2013
0  xxx  2020
```

Comment: So, In the end I used the ```get``` solution since I actually had a bigger dataset with different values so I couldn't apply the ```categorical`` solution in a easy way. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. -

```
df  =df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(sorted).explode().reset_index()
d = {'xxx': 4, 'zzz':1, 'yyy':5, 'kkk':2, 'jjj':3, 'www':0} 
df['sorted'] = df['col1'].map(d)
df = df.sort_values('sorted').drop('sorted', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change **col1** to be a categorical where it is ordered.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'kkk', 'www', 'www'],
                 "col2": [ 2020, 1994, 2013, 1000, 1996, 2021]})
d = {'xxx': 4, 'zzz':1, 'yyy':5, 'kkk':2, 'jjj':3, 'www':0} # to customize order 

df["col1"] = pd.Categorical(df["col1"], sorted(list(d.keys()), key=lambda x: d[x]), ordered=True)
df.sort_values(["col1","col2"])
```

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | www | 1996 |
| 5 | www | 2021 |
| 3 | kkk | 1000 |
| 1 | xxx | 1994 |
| 2 | xxx | 2013 |
| 0 | xxx | 2020 |

Answer (score 1):

create new column, map it to your dictionary, sort by it, then delete :)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'kkk', 'www', 'www'],
                 "col2": [ 2020, 1994, 2013, 1000, 1996, 2021]})

d = {'xxx': 4, 'zzz':1, 'yyy':5, 'kkk':2, 'jjj':3, 'www':0} # to customize order

df['sorting'] = df['col1'].map(d)
df = df.sort_values('sorting')
del df['sorting']
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a datatype "categorical" which can do that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'kkk', 'www', 'www'],
                 "col2": [ 2020, 1994, 2013, 1000, 1996, 2021]})

df["col1"] = pd.Categorical(df["col1"], ordered=True,
             categories=['www', 'zzz', 'kkk', 'jjj', 'xxx', 'yyy'])


df.sort_values(["col1", "col2"], ascending = (True, True))

  col1  col2
4  www  1996
5  www  2021
3  kkk  1000
1  xxx  1994
2  xxx  2013
0  xxx  2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not a bug. What do you expect from key when passing it to multiple columns? It will be applied to each of columns and used as sorting key. You don't have any of col2 elements in d, so it returns None (I think so because no error is raised, thus it may use `d.get(x, None)`). For your use case the most simple solution will be sorting twice:

```
df.sort_values(by='col2').sort_values(by='col1', key=lambda x: x.map(d))
```

I have also checked whether my assumptions were correct. If you set `key=x.map(lambda t: d[t])` instead of `x.map(d)` in your code example, error is raised saying that key is unmatched. So you really try to apply it to both columns and sort by results.